# Web3js raw transaction is being sent twice

Tags: express, web3js

I am sending a raw transaction to `Ropsten` test network with web3js module in node. The web3s code lives on an `express` back end. Here is the code:

```
var express = require("express");
var router = express.Router();

var Tx = require("ethereumjs-tx");
const Web3 = require("web3");
const web3 = new Web3(
  "https://ropsten.infura.io/v3/d55489f8ea264a1484c293b05ed7eb85"
);

const abi = [...];
const contractAddress = "0x15E1ff7d97CB0D7C054D19bCF579e3147FC9009b";
const myAccount = "0x59f568176e21EF86017EfED3660625F4397A2ecE";
const privateKey1 = new Buffer(
  "...",
  "hex"
);

hashValue = "newly updated value";

router.post("/", function(req, res, next) {
  const hashValue = req.body.hash,
    fileName = req.body.fileName,
    value = req.body.value;

  const contract = new web3.eth.Contract(abi, contractAddress, {
    from: myAccount
  });

  web3.eth.getTransactionCount(myAccount, (err, txCount) => {
    //Smart contract data
    const data = contract.methods
      .setHashValue(value + fileName + hashValue)
      .encodeABI();

    // Build the transaction
    const txObject = {
      nonce: web3.utils.toHex(txCount),
      gasLimit: web3.utils.toHex(1000000),
      gasPrice: 20000000000,
      data: data,
      from: myAccount,
      to: contractAddress
    };

    // Sign the transaction
    const tx = new Tx(txObject);
    tx.sign(privateKey1);

    const serializedTx = tx.serialize();
    // const raw = '0x' + serializedTx.toString('hex')

    // Broadcast the transaction
    web3.eth
      .sendSignedTransaction("0x" + serializedTx.toString("hex"))
      .on("receipt", console.log, receipt => {
        callback(receipt);
      })
      .then(() => {
        res.json({ transactionHash });
      })
      .catch(() => {
        // fail
      });
  });
});

module.exports = router;
```

The .post looks like this

```
axios.post(
        "http://compute.amazonaws.com:3000/users",
        {
          value: "value",
          fileName: "fileName",
          hash: "hash"
        }
      );
```

The transaction is successful and returns a json with all relevant block data. about 2-3 minutes later, the same transaction is sent and mined on `Ropsten`. About the time that the second transaction is mined, my console (the request is sent through an http from browser) shows the following errors:

```
POST http://ec2-54-67-28-69.us-west-1.compute.amazonaws.com:3000/users net::ERR_EMPTY_RESPONSE

createError.js:17 Uncaught (in promise) Error: Network Error
    at createError (createError.js:17)
    at XMLHttpRequest.handleError (xhr.js:87)
```

This didn't happen until I added

```
const hashValue = req.body.hash,
fileName = req.body.fileName,
value = req.body.value;
```

to the code.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This doesn't answer why the double transaction was happening, but a work around is to put `next()` at the end of the code.